# ReactJS - cannot redirect to a page using useCallback

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and am trying to just redirect to a page after part of a function has been executed. I cannot replicate the exact code as per my project so have created a demo, where the code is as follows:

```
import React, { useContext, useCallback } from "react";
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const account = true;

export default function App() {
  const callBack = useCallback(history.push("/login"), [history]);
  const handleLogin = () => {
    console.log("handleLogin");
    if (account) {
      localStorage.removeItem("testCookie");
    }

    callBack(); // needs to redirect to /login on this line
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleLogin}>click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have made a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-p9cr9e) for convenience.

However, I'm getting a Typescript error in my real application

```
Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(...args: any[]) => any'.  TS2345
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction for a fix for this? I wonder whether there's something obvious that I'm doing wrong or whether there is a different solution to just redirect to another page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useCallback` expects a function. Currently you're giving `history.push("/login")` which returns `void`.

So to answer your question in code, you're supposed to formulate it as `useCallback(() => history.push("/login"), [history]);`.

In your StackBlitz this won't work either way, because (`window.`)`history.push` is not a function. I think you want to use react-router-dom's `history` object (which does have a `push` function)?

```
export default function App() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const callBack = useCallback(() => history.push("/login"), [history]);
```